# Convert to png from a base64String of a word document in .doc format (mime application/octet-stream)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

As per research I found the way to convert my base64String of a word document to PNG.

1. By Using OpenXml ( it does not support .doc .. it only support docX )
2. Tried to convert the base64String to pdf by using iTextSharp ( but failed )

```
    byte[] fileContent = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();
    document.Add(Image.GetInstance(fileContent));
    document.Close();
```

*My word document contains image/tables and text.

Answer (score 0):

After decoding the base64 string to obtain the Word Document file, to access the file's contents for conversion to an image, you could look into using a library with the necessary components to handle and load the DOC format.

For example, the `RasterCodecs` class from the [LEADTOOLS SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/conversion) (Which is what I am familiar with since I work for the vendor), uses the file filters that comes with that library for loading and saving a DOC file as PNG. This would look something like this:

```
byte[] fileContent = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
MemoryStream DocStream = new MemoryStream(fileContent);
using (RasterCodecs codecs = new RasterCodecs())
{
   RasterImage image = codecs.Load(DocStream);
   codecs.Save(image, new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create), RasterImageFormat.Png, 0);
}
DocStream.Close();
```

You can also consider using Microsoft's [Office.Interop.Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word) for loading the DOC file, though you would have to implement conversion to PNG after this step.